# Python print/display only if the sum is not zero

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dataframe below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Product': ['A', 'A', 'C', 'D'], 'Volume': ['-3', '3', '1', '5']})
```

I am using groupby and sum.

```
final = df.groupby(['Product'])['Volume'].sum().reset_index()
print(final)
```

This is ok.
But I only want the print to be carry only those where sum != 0. Like Product C and D

Any idea how can I do that?
I try to use:

```
if final != 0:
    print (final)
```

But this is throwing error and usually when I get this error, the syntax is definitely wrong...

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data frame has Volume as strings, is that intended? if you want to sum it like numbers you have to convert it to numbers then you can apply the filter.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Product': ['A', 'A', 'C', 'D'], 'Volume': ['-3', '3', '1', '5']})
# convert from string to integers
df.Volume = df.Volume.map(lambda x: int(x)) 
final = df.groupby(['Product'])['Volume'].sum().reset_index()
#choose ones with sum none zero
print(final[final.Volume != 0])
```

it will print only the C & D

Comment: Thank you so much. i did not realize that is not int...stupid me trying to solve for past 1 hour

Answer (score 0):

Given,

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Product': ['A', 'A', 'C', 'D'], 'Volume': [-3, 3, 1, 5]})
final = df.groupby(['Product'])['Volume'].sum().reset_index()
```

Use selection to only select rows that match your criteria. `df[some_series_of_booleans_based_on_condition]`

```
print(final[final['Volume'] != 0])
#output:
  Product  Volume
1       C       1
2       D       5
```

The idea being that `if [some series of booleans]:` doesn't make sense for python to interpret, and thus it complains about the syntax with the message that you saw.

Comment: Thank you so much. i did not realize that is not int...stupid me trying to solve for past 1 hour